# Посчитать зарплату всех подчиненных

Tags: sql, oracle, запрос

Вот таблица:

```
create table test_table (
id integer not null,
name char(1) not null,
parent_id integer,
sum integer not null);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(1, 'A', null, 300);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(11, 'B', 1, 2340);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(111, 'C', 11, 3200);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(22, 'D', 1, 7540);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(2, 'E', null, 6300);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(3, 'F', 2, 8600);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(101, 'G', 3, 3800);
INSERT INTO test_table VALUES(102, 'H', 3, 9700);
```

Вот код:

```
SELECT distinct sum, name,
CASE level
  WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT SUM(SUM) 
                     FROM test_table 
                     WHERE level > 1
                     START WITH parent_id is null 
                     CONNECT BY prior id = parent_id)
  WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT SUM(SUM) 
                     FROM test_table 
                     WHERE level > 2 
                     START WITH parent_id is null 
                     CONNECT BY prior id = parent_id)
  WHEN 3 THEN null
END AS SUM_SUM
FROM test_table 
START WITH parent_id is null
CONNECT BY prior id = parent_id
order by name;
```

Есть конкретный вопрос, есть более общий. Конкретный: как посчитать зарплату всех подчиненных, при этом зарплата начальника не учитывается. Общий - как отделить подчиненных одного начальника от другого? Т.к. в этом запросе выдается зп всех подчиненных, имеющий level больше, чем у начальника.

Пример выходных данных:

```
CREATE TABLE result_tbl (
id integer not null,
name char(1) not null,
parent_id integer,
sum integer not null);
INSERT INTO result_tbl VALUES(1, 'A', null, 12080);
INSERT INTO result_tbl VALUES(11, 'B', 1, 3200);
INSERT INTO result_tbl VALUES(111, 'C', 11, 0);
INSERT INTO result_tbl VALUES(22, 'D', 1, 0);
INSERT INTO result_tbl VALUES(2, 'E', null, 22100);
INSERT INTO result_tbl VALUES(3, 'F', 2, 13500);
INSERT INTO result_tbl VALUES(101, 'G', 3, 9700);
INSERT INTO result_tbl VALUES(102, 'H', 3, 0);
```

Comment: А чем запись начальника отличается от записи подчиненного?

Comment: id начальника есть parent_id подчиненного

Comment: Зарплата подчиненных - это зарплата одной ветки рекурсии на текущем уровне ? Вы могли бы на основе приведенных тестовых данных написать табличку какой результат должен получится

Comment: Хотя начинаю понемногу понимать ... Я понимаю что такое зарплата подчиненных по иерархии конкретного начальника. Но что такое "всех подчиненных", вам нужно 2 цифры - по иерархии и так, как вы это делаете сейчас - всех выше уровнем ? И кстати почему для level 3 сумма не предусмотрена

Comment: для level 3 сумма не предусмотрена, потому что у него нет подчиненных. Кстати, да, если решать общую задачу, а не эту конкретную, то у level 3 может быть подчиненный, тогда получается, что CASE применить не получится?

Comment: "всех подчиненных" - это и есть сумма зп по иерархии конкретного начальника

Comment: Кстати пример выходных можно было без create table а от руки как выглядит вывод. но и так конечно все ясно. правда там ошибки в некоторых суммах у A она 13080, у G нет наследников и она должна быть 0.

Comment: И если не трудно, могли бы Вы подсказать ресурсы, где можно порешать подобные задачи, разобраться нормально, а то на конкретные реализации пространства stack overflow не хватит)

Comment: @daydark Я только sql-ex.ru знаю и то по рекомендациям, сам не пользовался. И там акцент на sql-server, так что конкретно `connect by` там вряд ли есть. Рекурсии там через CTE решаются (впрочем oracle CTE то же понимает)

Comment: @daydark И кстати периодические ответы на stackoveflow это хорошая школа. правда действительно интересные задачи (а не как выбрать все из таблицы) довольно редки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select id, name, parent_id, 
       ( select nvl(sum(sum),0)
           from test_table B
          start with B.parent_id=A.id  -- Получать только подчиненных конкретной ветви
        connect by prior id=parent_id
       ) as sum_sum
  from test_table A
```

Второй вариант:

```
select id, name, sum(sum)-max(root_sum)
  from (
    select connect_by_root(id) id, connect_by_root(name) name,
           connect_by_root(sum) root_sum, sum
      from test_table A
   connect by prior id=parent_id
  )
 group by id, name
```

В нем нет указания `start with`, поэтому `connect by` все записи таблицы считает корневыми и для каждой записи создает на выходе все ее подчиненные (многие записи дублируются). Функция `connect_by_root` возвращает указанное поле той записи, с которой началась данная ветвь выдачи. Таким образом мы можем получить суммы для каждого отдельного корня, но в него будет входить и сама сумма корневой записи, поэтому на заключительном этапе нам надо будет ее вычесть.