# Создание рекурсивного запроса с выводом пути, иерархического древа и суммы зарплат

Tags: oracle, plsql

Здравствуйте. Как в рекурсивном запросе с использованием CTE сохранить иерархическую структуру и при этом посчитать суммарную зарплату не только верхушки иерархии, но и всех узлов, исключая низшие у которых нет детей.
Исходная таблица выглядит следующим образом

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получилось добиться нужного результата используя 2 CTE таблицы.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С помощью вот такого запроса

```
with C(id_working,salary,RootID,RootID_B) as
(
  select --0 as lvl,
         company_2.id_working,
         company_2.salary,
         company_2.id_working as RootID,
         company_2.id_boss as RootID_B
  from company_2 
  union all
  select --lvl+1,
         company_2.id_working,
         company_2.salary,
         C.RootID,
         C.RootID_B
  from company_2
    inner join C 
      on company_2.id_boss = C.id_working)
, 
t1(lvl,bname, id_boss,id_working,path) as 
(select 1 AS lvl, t.bname, t.id_boss,
t.id_working, '' AS path
from company_2 t where t.id_boss is null
union all
select lvl+1, t2.bname, t2.id_boss,t2.id_working, ltrim((t1.path||','||t1.bname),',') AS path
from 
company_2 t2 join t1 on 
t2.id_boss=t1.id_working
) 
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY path SET orderval
select S_2.tree,
       S.sumsal,
       S_2.path
       --orderval
       --S_2.bname
       --RPAD('.', (lvl-1)*2, '.') || id AS tree,
       --C.lvl
from company_2
       full join (
             select RootID,RootID_B,
                    (sum(salary)-min(salary)) as sumsal,
                    count(salary) as count_sal
             from C
             group by RootID, RootID_B
             having count(salary)>1
             ) S
    on company_2.id_working = S.RootID
    full join (select orderval, id_working,RPAD(' ', (lvl-1)*2, ' ') || bname AS tree, path from t1) S_2 on company_2.id_working=S_2.id_working
    order by S_2.orderval

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiMVM.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/utIKf.jpg
```

Но как добиться таких же результатов с 1 CTE?

Comment: И как что либо делать, если надо час потратить на то что бы перебить ваши данные с картинки в текстовый вид ? Приведите данные в виде текста, (в идеале в виде insert для создания таблицы) и небольшое пояснение что же надо получить

Comment: и что то мне подсказывает, что действительно после первого CTE данных уже достаточно, что бы их сгруппировать и вывести. только надо немного подумать над формированием нужного порядка сортировки. думаю получение пути в первой части запроса могло бы помоч

Comment: Кстати, очень похожая задача (если не точно такая) https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/585879/194569

Comment: Задача действительно точно такая же, спасибо, но реализовать такую штуку conect by не сложно. А вот посредством cte таблиц я как-то туплю. В любом случае спасибо, буду разбираться :)

Comment: С CTE то же самое, я бы предложил сформировать path из id, что бы не было пересечений. Ваша первая CTE фактически готовит исходные данные точно такие же как connect by. Ваша задача их правильно сгруппировать, видимо по root, и отсортировать (возможно по path или path из id)

Comment: Проблема в том, что если оставить лишь одну CTE при этом указав в рекурсивной части условие id_boss is null - указав тем самым родителей, то зарплата считается исключительно для родителей у которых id_boss является null, а не для всех подчиненных. В том, чтобы составить иерархическое древо с одним запросом проблем нет. Основная проблема правильно найти суммы зарплат(как показано на втором рисунке). Вот

Comment: На это я уже ничего не могу сказать, мне надо видеть живые данные у себя в таблице. Хотя ... если вы все таки сделаете path из id как я предложил, и отсортируете данные по нему (особенно если lpad дополните все id до фиксированной длины, для правильной текстовой сортировки), то у вас получится на выходе аккуратное дерево, начинающееся с одного из боссов и идущее вниз к подчиненным. если надо при этом поставить красивые пробелы и т.п. посчитайте (снаружи от CTE) например max(lvl), что бы знать сколько же пробелов ставить

Comment: Так же можно с помощью lead пометить строки, после которых путь сбивается, а не продолжает данную ветвь, таким образом должно получиться отфильтровать листья

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with RCTE(root_id,name,root_sum,sum,id,path,lvl) as(
    select id, name, sum, sum, id,
           lpad(id,10,'0'), 0
      from test_table
  union all
    select R.root_id, R.name, R.root_sum, T.sum, T.id,
           R.path||'/'||lpad(T.id,10,'0'), lvl+1
      from RCTE R, test_table T
     where T.parent_id=R.id
)
select root_id, RPAD(' ', (min(max_lvl))*2, '-') ||name,
       sum(sum)-max(root_sum), min(full_path)
  from (
    select R.*, first_value(path) over(partition by id order by lvl desc) full_path,
           max(lvl) over(partition by id) max_lvl
      from RCTE R
  ) X
 group by root_id, name
 order by min(full_path)
```

Для правильного вывода в виде дерева получаем для каждого id путь, где данный id имеет максимальный уровень вложенности (т.е. самый длинный путь в котором он участвует) и сортируем по этому пути. для правильных отступов берем сначала для каждого id максимальный уровень. А при группировке по корню, так как у нас присутствуют все записи от данного уровня и ниже, берем минимальный уровень из них (это и есть уровень корня)

Comment: Стараюсь применить данный код к своим таблицам, получаю ошибку "Результат строковой конкатенации слишком велик", хотя делая из вашего кода путь не из айдишников, а из имен такой ошибки нет. :( Может у вас есть предположения с чем это связанно?

Comment: @МакиБольшой сделайте lpad по меньше, у вас id сейчас 4 знака, думаю 6 должно на долго хватить. кроме того разделитель `/` там для читабельности человеком, сортировка отлично отработает и если id будут в притык друг к другу

Comment: Спасибо большое за помощь. Я переделал изначальную таблицу и по всей видимости в самой таблице была ошибка. Ваши примеры и объяснения очень помогли. :) Спасибо!

Comment: Но у меня снова есть к вам вопрос, простите, что так надоедаю. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы напротив корневых записей не были указаны их пути(то есть они сами). Заменяю lpad(id,10,'0') на ''(пустые ковычки) и получаю ту же ошибку связанную с конкатенацией.

Comment: @МакиБольшой А если что нибудь вроде `cast('' as varchar2(2000))`

Comment: Избавляет от ошибки, но ломает иерархию. Думаю substr просто вырезать неугодные слова - это топорно правда получится, но может сработает.

Comment: @МакиБольшой А кто вас заставляет сортировать по тому же полю, которое выводите. Сделайте два поля, для отображения и для сортировки

Answer (score 0):

```
with RCTE(root_id,name,root_sum,sum,id,path,lvl) as(
    select id, name, sum, sum, id,
      name, 0
      from company_4
  union all
    select R.root_id, R.name, R.root_sum, T.sum, T.id,
          R.path||','||T.name, lvl+1
      from RCTE R join company_4 T
     on T.parent_id=R.id
)
SEARCH DEPTH FIRST BY id SET orderval
select RPAD(' ', (min(max_lvl))*2) ||name as tree,
       /*min(full_path) as bosses,name,*/
       SUBSTR(min(full_path), 1, INSTR(min(full_path), ',', -1) -1),
       nullif(sum(sum)-max(root_sum),0) as sumsal
  from (
    select R.*, first_value(path) IGNORE NULLS over(partition by id order by lvl desc) full_path,
           max(lvl) over(partition by id) max_lvl
      from RCTE R
  ) X
 group by root_id,name 
 order by min(full_path);
```

тащемто мой вариант кода